# How to fix PrepareStatement points to null?

Tags: java

Prepare statement points to null somehow and I cannot see a reasonable cause for it. I am trying to understand what is wrong so why it points to null. I have tried to use "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" instead of "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" but it seemed irrelevant.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        saveData();
    }

    public static void saveData() throws Exception{

        Car Ford = new Car();

        Ford.setType("Car");
        Ford.setModel("Ford");
        Ford.setColour("Black");
        Ford.setSunroof(true);
        Ford.setDoor(4);

        String query = "INSERT INTO sys.homework(ID,type,colour,sunroof,model,door)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        try{
            Connection con = getConnection();

            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query); //Debugger points this line

            ps.setInt(1,12);
            ps.setString(2, Ford.getType());
            ps.setString(3,Ford.getColour());
            ps.setBoolean(4,Ford.isSunroof());
            ps.setString(5, Ford.getModel());
            ps.setInt(6, Ford.getDoor());

            ps.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch (SQLException sql) {
            sql.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sys?useUnicode=true&usetetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Germany","root","pass");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sample.Main.saveData(Main.java:26)
```

Comment: @NathanHughes I have it in my classpath

Comment: Even if the driver is in the classpath, you're always returning `null` from `getConnection`.

Comment: Which line is 26?

Comment: @rgettman what should I return instead of?

Comment: @Clay - you shouldn't return anything.  You should be letting the exception propagate ... and dealing with is at a higher level.  Also it is a really bad idea to catch Exception or declare a method to `throw Exception`.

Comment: But the real problem is that you don't have the JAR file containing that database driver on the classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" instead of "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" but it seemed irrelevant.

It quite possibly is relevant.  But by your report it is not the complete solution.

The real problem is one *or both* of the following:

- The JAR file containing the JDBC driver may not be on the classpath.
- You may be using the wrong class name for the JDBC driver:

  - For older versions of the MySQL Connector/J Driver the name is `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.
  - For newer versions it is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`
  - The change happened with the 8.0 release.

I would also like to point out that a lot of your problems are attributable to some implementation mistakes:

- You should not catch `Exception`.  Catch only the exceptions that you know how to handle.
- You typically should not use `printStackTrace()` in an exception handler.  Exceptions should be logged.  Scattering calls to print stacktraces makes it harder to maintain production code.
- You should not declare a method as `throws Exception`.  That means the caller has to be able to deal with *all* exceptions, and has little idea what to expect.
- It is typically a bad idea to return `null` if there is an error.  Either let the exception propagate to where it can be *effectively* handled, or wrap it in a different exception and throw that instead.

What happens at the moment is that any error in the `getConnection` method causes it to return `null`.  And the code that calls `getConnnection` is not dealing with this properly ... leading to `NullPointerException`.  So where you had one problem, you now have two.

---

Finally, if you look carefully at your code, you will see that there is a bug that causes it to *always* return `null`.  Even if there isn't an exception.

Answer (score -2):

You need to return the connection in the try block.

```
public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sys?useUnicode=true&usetetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Germany","root","pass");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        return con;
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Catching all exceptions and returning null is a bad choice.  Declaring a method as `throws Exception` is a bad choice.

Comment: Copying the OP's bad choices into a solution is a bad choice.